# How can I record breathing as an input in raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm a little new to raspberry pi and my understanding is that you can take in an input like a button press, then you'll be able to do whatever you want in your code with that input. I'm wondering if it's possible to take your breathing as an input so as to record my inhalations and exhalations?

Also if it's possible, what would I need to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its possible if you use a right sensor (for example a microphone - https://thepihut.com/products/mini-usb-microphone) and code it right.
If you need a really precise data, i recommend using a better sensor with better quality. Most of microphones outputs analog data which can you sample later and get the data you need! If you have any questions, you can ask in the comments

Comment: Perfect thanks, that's very helpful. Do you have any recommendations for more precise data?

Comment: @Abc Hi, depends how much are you willing to spend od the gear. Analog data in general are not perfect because of the wires and all the interference, so if you want your data to be really precise, i recommend using the best gear possible and giving the machine perfect conditions